# how to concat two arrays in jq

Tags: json, parsing, jq

I have the following json:

```
echo '{"a": [1, 3, 5, 7, 9 ], "b": [2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ]}' | jq                                                                                                                                                    
{
  "a": [
    1,
    3,
    5,
    7,
    9
  ],
  "b": [
    2,
    4,
    6,
    8,
    10
  ]
}
```

I would like to get the following csv:

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
7,8
9,10
```

How is this possible with jq?

Comment: Are you looking for something else other than this  `echo '{"a": [1, 3, 5, 7, 9 ], "b": [2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ]}' | jq '[.a, .b] | transpose | @csv'` ????

Comment: @Raky You cannot use `@csv` on an array of arrays. You have to at least iterate over the outer array first. Also, you may want to get rid of the JSON-encoding by using the `-r` flag.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `transpose`. It "rotates" a table by taking a an array of arrays. Iterate over the rotated rows, and use `@csv` to generate the CSV:

```bash
jq -r '[.a, .b] | transpose[] | @csv'
```

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
7,8
9,10
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/3TiiEb4Be57)

Note: If the arrays had unequal lengths, `transpose` would fill in `null`s, resulting in empty items for the the CSV.